# Stop the Running process of taskmgr from PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I write this command for powershell. I want to stop the running process of taskmgr from PowerShell.

```
Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}
```

And how to stop process those running processes?

Comment: So you are trying to kill every single running service on a PC?

Answer (score 0):

Task Manager is a process, not a service.
So, in order to stop it from PowerShell you need to run:

```
Stop-Process -Name Taskmgr -Force
```

PS: You will need to run the powershell as administrator in order to stop the process.
Best regards,

Comment: can I do this  Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Stop-Process

Comment: I want to stop process just for the running

Comment: @Arshavink, you are mixing up services (`Get-Service`) and processes (`Stop-Process`). Are you trying to stop all running services (very bad idea), all running processes (very bad idea), or a specific process (maybe ok)?